# Is there a current solution for Amazon AWS Connect Voicemail?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect, voicemail

My company is currently looking to build a power dialer using AWS Amazon Connect but I haven't been able to find support for agent extensions or voicemail. I'm, I going crazy? Someone please point me in the right direction.

Comment: https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com works

Answer (score 1):

We faced similar challenges and after several attempts discovered https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com .  It was easy to integrate into our current Amazon Connect instance.

Answer (score 1):

AWS has recently released Voicemail for Amazon Connect, which is deployed using a CloudFormation template.

You only pay for the standard AWS charges that the solution uses, there's no additional platform/service charges.

https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/voicemail-for-amazon-connect/

Comment: You should know Amazon does not provide support for these types of solutions. If you want production proven, supported software I'd recommend https://amazonconnectvoicemail.com for voicemail